# All the reasons a Linux server might freeze

Tags: linux, remote, server-crashes, system-monitoring

Every now and then, one of our remote Linux servers crashes: they're unavailable on the network (sometimes responding to a ping, but not to ssh/http) and they won't respond to mouse or keyboard input.

The servers are high-quality consumer grade hardware running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Since these crashes happen infrequently, I'm collecting all the *common* reasons a server might crash like that so I can set up monitoring (munin) to make sure I have all the information needed when it happens and implement countermeasures (eg. periodic restarts?).

## Question:

What are reasons for a Linux computer to become unresponsive, what info can I track to diagnose these issues, what can I do to fix them?

I believe this question and answers will be most useful if there's one answer per cause of failure and I'll be posting answers myself as I find such causes.

Comment: Sometimes the kernel will record the reason it hangs to the console and/or create a crashdump so definitely configure that those get a) generated b) captured c) investigated. -_-_-_ But *"servers"*  &  *"consumer grade hardware"*  - sigh - one of the nice things in server hardware are the out-of-band management consoles that can collect and report on hardware errors and other events that kill the operating system (before the OS  can record the error). -

Comment: OOB management is a very good point, @HBruijn .
Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how this will be all that useful. There's *nothing* in your logs?

Comment: @ceejayoz I didn't find anything, but then it hasn't happened very often, so far, and I got notified only days after the incidents with no precise information about when it happened.

Comment: It's more about a general list of things to track and things to log and reasons to look for when it happened in this particular and other settings where a system suddenly stops working.

Answer (score 0):

### Reason: Excessive swapping

can cause a system freeze (though this would usually be transient).

*Track:* RAM and swap usage

*Fix:* Increase RAM, tune services, (maybe) increase swap

See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/762366/linux-swapping-blocks-system-freeze)

Answer (score 0):

### Reason: Excessive RAM/CPU usage

*Track:* RAM and swap usage, resource-hungry processes, their logs

*Fix:* Increase RAM, tune services, debug resource-hungry processes to see under which conditions their resource consumption spikes

Answer (score 0):

### Reason: HD Write Failures

*Track:* [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) diagnostics

*Fix:* Replace failing disks

Answer (score -1):

You have nice pointers here from the previous comments.

You might also want to stop your server for a weekend (if possible) and test the ram with Memtest86.

You burn a cd or a iso to a usb key and start the machine with it.
I understand you have physical access to it.